# How do you for each on XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Im trying to grab the channel display name and channel id from some XML data but it cant seem to get it to work. For each channel display name I what to grab the channel display name and channel id, this is what I have tried, it grabs the data but it puts them all into one string and I want them on separate lines.

```
var xml = "<tv generator-info-name='tvchannels' source-info-name='tvchannels'><channel id='1234'><display-name>Channel 1</display-name></channel><channel id='5678'><display-name>Channel 2</display-name></channel><channel id='543553'><display-name>Channel 3</display-name></channel><channel id='324324'><display-name>Channel 4</display-name></channel></tv>",

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc );

$xml.find("display-name").each(
        function (i,e) {

$('#title').append($xml.find("display-name"));

$('#channelid').append($xml.find("channel").attr("id"));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

XPATH and XSL/XSLT do this, however they can be difficult to learn/use compared to javascript/JSON. JavaScript Object Notation, JSON, is preferred. Have a look at

[XPath Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft

[Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) from MDN.

> #### Iterator Example
>
> ```
> var iterator = document.evaluate('//phoneNumber', documentNode, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );
>
> try {
>   var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
>   
>   while (thisNode) {
>     alert( thisNode.textContent );
>     thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
>   }   
> }
> catch (e) {
>   alert( 'Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When you're looping through `$xml`, you need to use `$(this)` or the second argument passed to `.each()` in order to access the individual channels as you're looping through. See the code below:

```js
var xml = "<tv generator-info-name='tvchannels' source-info-name='tvchannels'><channel id='1234'><display-name>Channel 1</display-name></channel><channel id='5678'><display-name>Channel 2</display-name></channel><channel id='543553'><display-name>Channel 3</display-name></channel><channel id='324324'><display-name>Channel 4</display-name></channel></tv>",

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc );

$xml.find('channel').each(function (i,e) {
  $('#title').append($(this).find("display-name"));
  $('#title').append($('<br />'));

  $('#channelid').append($(this).attr("id"));
  $('#channelid').append($('<br />'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Titles: <br />
<div id="title"></div><br />
Channel IDs: <br />
<div id="channelid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the results of the find method. I believe you need smth like

```js
var xml = "<tv generator-info-name='tvchannels' source-info-name='tvchannels'><channel id='1234'><display-name>Channel 1</display-name></channel><channel id='5678'><display-name>Channel 2</display-name></channel><channel id='543553'><display-name>Channel 3</display-name></channel><channel id='324324'><display-name>Channel 4</display-name></channel></tv>",

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc );

$xml.find("channel").each(function(index, e) {
    $('#title').append($(e).find("display-name").text() + '<br />');

    $('#channelid').append(e.getAttribute("id") + '<br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="channelid"></div>
```